# How can we get the execution context of a function?

Tags: javascript

Let say we declare a variable in the global context, like so:

```
var someVariable = "someValue";
```

We can always access its value like `window['someVariable']` as it is in the global execution context.
But, how can we access it value the same way if it is inside some function and not in the global execution context? For e.g.

```
function someFunction(someParameter) {
  var someVariable = "some value";
  // some code
}
```

I want to do something like `someFucntionContext['someParameter']` or `someFucntionContext['someVariable']` to access the value of those variables in the execution context of the `someFucntion` like I just did for the variable declared in the global context.

Comment: Not possible via any built-in method. You'll have to manually expose the information you want to be made public.

Comment: `someParameter` is just an alias of the value which you pass into the function `someFunction` as a parameter. It is not declared or initialize anywhere in the syatem so it cannot be accessible the way you are asking as that variable do not exist at all.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Please read my updated question. :)

Comment: You are confusing the execution context with a variable scope.

Comment: You are confusing the [execution context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384758/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript-exactly/50512406#50512406) with a variable scope. And the latter [is not an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40544709/why-variable-object-was-changed-to-lexical-environment-in-es5).

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible without returning objects or instantiating the function and accessing the property.

Global variables are automatically a property of the `window` object, provided you use `var` and not `let` or `const`. Such as root level functions being automatically a method of the `window` object. But functions do not behave like primitive objects. You need to do something like

```
function Favorites(){
  return{
     food: "burrito",
     color: "gray"
  }
}

var fav = Favorites();
var favfood = fav.food; //fav['food']
```

OR

```
function Favorites(){
  this.food = "burrito";
  this.color = "gray";
}

var fav = new Favorites();
var favfood = fav.food; //fav['food']
```

And like so

```
var favfood = window.fav.food;
var favcolor = window['fav']['color']
```

Comment: Nitpicking: A function is an object. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449596/every-object-is-a-function-and-every-function-is-object-which-is-correct

Comment: I understand the nitpickiness, this is a community where you really have to be nitpicky. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach could be exposing certain properties of the function itself.

```
function fn(){
  fn.num = 100;
}
//access fn.num
console.log(fn["num"])
```

You can control which properties you want to expose from the function itself. For example,

```
function doSomething(num, addStr){
  //expose num
  doSomething.num = num;
  var str = "Hello ";
  if(addStr){
    str += addStr;
  }
  //expose str
  doSomething.str = str;
}

//set num
doSomething(100);

//access num
console.log(doSomething.num)
console.log(doSomething["num"])

//set num and str
doSomething(200, "Jerry!")

//access str
console.log(doSomething["str"])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(0, eval)("this").someVariable
```

The reasons for this are pretty esoteric, but essentially by calling `eval("this")`, you are evaluating `this` in the current execution context.  And putting it in the `(0, eval)` construct forces it to execute in the global context, so you always get the *correct* `this` - the global object - which allows you to access globals anywhere.

Another way to put it:

```
function foo() {
  const global = (0, eval)("this");
  global.someVariable = 13;
}
```

Notably, the `0` can be pretty much anything.  The important bit is that the `eval` is not evaluated in isolation which would tie it to the current execution context, and is instead executed in the global one.  With that bit of magic, the expression `(a, b)` evaluates to `b` per normal Javascript rules, so you get `eval`, but it's within the global context.

Also, if you don't need to update the variable you can use a shortcut:

```
(0, eval)("someVariable")
```

For an important workaround in some contexts, see [How to get the global object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277182/how-to-get-the-global-object-in-javascript)

Comment: OP did not ask how to access the global object. They were asking for a "local object" of their function.

Comment: Question could be clearer, but yes I do now see what you're saying.